# Occurrence of list in ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, numpy-ndarray

I have an RGB image -ndarray- and I want to count the occurrence of some colors like [255,0,0] or [0,0,255] in this image.

example of image data

```
np.ones((3, 3, 3)) * 255

array([[[255., 255., 255.],
        [255., 255., 255.],
        [255., 255., 255.]],
       [[255., 255., 255.],
        [255., 255., 255.],
        [255., 255., 255.]],
       [[255., 255., 255.],
        [255., 255., 255.],
        [255., 255., 255.]]])
```

So as result I want something like this

```
{
'[255,255,255]' : 9,
}
```

Comment: I added an example. so in general the dimension of RGB image is (width, height, 3)

Comment: np.unique can be used in the linked dupe @MatteoPeluso being a 1d array. However with a 2darray its a little more tricky :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whereas its possible to use `Counter` or [opencv histogram function](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d1/db7/tutorial_py_histogram_begins.html) to compute frequency of every single pixel , for specific pixels, its more efficient to use this:

```
import numpy as np

ar = np.ones([3,3,3]) *255
ar[1,1,:] = [0, 0, 200]

pixels = dict()
pixels['[255, 255, 255]'] =  np.sum(np.all(ar == [255,255, 255], axis = 2))
pixels['[0, 0, 200]'] =  np.sum(np.all(ar == [0, 0, 200], axis = 2))
```

result : `{'[255, 255, 255]': 8, '[0, 0, 200]': 1}`

Answer (score 4):

One solution could be the `Counter` function:

```
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np

# Generate some data
data = np.ones((10, 20, 3)) * 255

# Convert to tuple list
data_tuple = [ tuple(x) for x in data.reshape(-1,3)]
Counter(data_tuple)
```

Returns:

```
Counter({(255.0, 255.0, 255.0): 200})
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. It works very well but it takes long time

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach using `NumPy`. Being values in the range 0-255, we could view the rows as tuples with three elements of type `f8`, and use `np.unique` to count the occurrences of the actual rows in the original ndarray. Using nakor's array:

```
a = np.ones((10, 20, 3)) * 255
```

We could then do:

```
vals, counts = np.unique(a.view('f8,f8,f8'), return_counts=True)
```

Where:

```
print(vals)
array([(255., 255., 255.)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<f8'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '<f8')])

print(counts)
array([200])
```

Comment: I tried with a real picture and I had this error `ValueError: When changing to a larger dtype, its size must be a divisor of the total size in bytes of the last axis of the array.`